# How to resolve mismatch module name in haskell stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, bnfc

I have some haskell modules generated which is named `Par.hs` in `Bnfc/Par.hs`

The generated module is

```hs
module Bnfc.Abs where
```

in my library referencing this is

```hs
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import Bnfc.Abs
import Text.Printf
```

and my `package.yaml` with `stack` is configured like such

```yaml
library:
  source-dirs: 
    - src
    - Bnfc
```

```
    File name does not match module name:
    Saw: ‘Bnfc.Par’
    Expected: ‘Par’
  |
9 | module Bnfc.Par
```

Yet I am getting the above error when running `stack ghci`. I don't understand what I did incorrectly?

Comment: Could you post the `tree` output for your project (excluding `.stack-work` etc.)?

Comment: @sjakobi Thanks for the hint. I figured out what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is the issue.

I moved `Bnfc` folder into the `src` folder and the hierarchy works because when compiling haskell treat the directory under `source-dirs` as root.